# What is the authenticity of the narration that says that Jesus (Alayhisalam) was raised from Mt.Olives in Israel?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, authenticity, reference-request

Where can I find this narration? Here is the original Arabic text of the narration that says that Jesus (Alayhisalam) was raised from Mt.Olives in Israel:-

**عن صفية أم المؤمنين رضي الله عنها أنها كانت إذا زارت بيت المقدس ، وفرغت من الصلاة في المسجد الأقصى صعدت على جبل زيتا فصلت عليه وقالت : هذا الجبل هو الذي رفع منه عيسى عليه السلام إلى السماء**

**Where can I find this narration? Where is the chain of narrators and what is the authenticity of this narration?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This wording has been recorded by Kashmiri in [التصريح بما تواتر في نزول المسيح](https://al-maktaba.org/book/8575/158), cited from a persian tafsir called فتح العزیز or  تفسیر عزیزی, written by Shah Abdul Aziz Dehlavi - in the tafsir or Surah at-Tin (urdu translation [here](https://archive.org/details/JawahirEAzeeziUrduTarjmaTafseerEAzeezi/%D8%AC%D9%88%D8%A7%DA%BE%D8%B1%20%D8%B9%D8%B2%DB%8C%D8%B2%DB%8C%20%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%B3%DB%8C%D8%B1%20%D8%B9%D8%B2%DB%8C%D8%B2%DB%8C%20%D9%BE%D8%A7%D8%B1%DB%81%2030%20/page/n455/mode/2up)). There is no chain cited for it there and I could not find it elsewhere in a cursory search.

Comment: Well done I was wondering what was meant with the note "ذكره في تفسير ((فتح العزيز)) في سورة التين. " because my information was that al-Kashmiri was also known for his commentary on ibn al-Humam's work فتح القدير. And I couldn't find a Tafsir called فتح العزيز nor  تفسير عزيزي in Arabic.

Answer (score 0):

It is reported in the Acts of the Apostles, written by Luke, which is estimated a very reliable source in Christanity. Luke was not an eye-witness but had direct contact to eye-witnesses.

Acts, 1:9-12

> And when he had said this, as they were looking on, he was lifted up,
> and a cloud took him out of their sight. And while they were gazing
> into heaven as he went, behold, two men stood by them in white robes,
> and said, "Men of Galilee, why do you stand looking into heaven? This
> Jesus, who was taken up from you into heaven, will come in the same
> way as you saw him go into heaven." Then they returned to Jerusalem
> from the mount called Olivet, which is near Jerusalem, a sabbath day's
> journey away;

The Hadit drefers th this.